# Issue with using DropBox Java SDK while migrating from Spring5 to Spring6

Tags: spring-mvc, dropbox-sdk

We plan to migrate to spring6 from spring5 and were using dropbox library.
Now with spring6, since we need to use jakarta namespace and dropbox latest v5.4.4 maven dependency still uses javax namespace internally, we are kind of stuck.

Please help us with any alternative solution

Thanks
Ramesh